# wp_title() handling of author page

Tags: page-template, author, functions, title

Why doesn't wp_title() display the author's name on an author archive as it does for a category or date archive? How can I hack this functionality?

header.php calls:

```
<title><?php wp_title ( '|', true,'right' ); ?></title>
```

Here is my author.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php   
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    get_userdata(intval($author));
    function validate_gravatar($email) {
    // Craft a potential url and test its headers
    $hash = md5($email);
    $uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash . '?d=404';
    $headers = @get_headers($uri);
    if (!preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) {
        $has_valid_avatar = FALSE;
    } else {
        $has_valid_avatar = TRUE;
    }
    return $has_valid_avatar;
}
$user_email = $curauth->user_email;
$has_avatar = validate_gravatar($user_email);
?>


  <div class="content-title">About <?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?></div>

  <div id="curauth" class="post-content">
  <div id="avatar"><?php if($has_avatar) {echo get_avatar($curauth->ID, 70);} ?></div>
  <?php if ($curauth->user_description) : ?>
   <p><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></p>
   <?php endif; 
   if ($curauth->user_url) : ?>
   <p><a href="<?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?></a></p>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if (!$curauth->user_description && !$curauth->user_url) : ?>
   <p>A riddle wrapped in a mystery inside an enigma...</p>
   <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="content-title">Contact</div>
  <div id="curauth" class="post-content">
  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form 1 "Contact Author"]' ); ?>
  </div>


<div class="content-title">
  <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
  <?php _e('Author Archive'); ?>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" id="mode"<?php if ($_COOKIE['mode'] == 'grid') echo ' class="flip"'; ?>></a> </div>
<ul>
<!-- The Loop -->
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see my name in the title when viewing author pages.

[image]

`wp_title()` runs this code during execution..

```
// If there's an author
if ( is_author() ) {
    $author = get_queried_object();
    $title = $author->display_name;
}
```

Perhaps your author(s) don't have a display name set?

Additionally be sure to try disabling plugins that may be hooking a filter onto `wp_title` and check your theme's function file for functions that hook on to...

Comment: Nope they all do. For example: http://www.mbird.com/author/sysadmin/ - Its displaying the name of my blog again.

Comment: Tried with plugins disabled? Alot of SEO related plugins like to hook onto `wp_title` and change things..

Comment: .. or under another theme(to rule out a theme specific function being at fault)...

Comment: Nothing hooks into wp_title(). If you navigate around the site, you can see the function working well on other pages.

Comment: Does switching theme resolve the problem? Not suggesting it as a solution, just a means to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I can't easily switch the theme, as the site is live. I guess I just have study Twenty Ten's `author.php` vs mine (shown in full above). I can tell you that `<div><?php echo is_author(); ?></div>` is printing '1', so I'm pretty baffled. Maybe `wp_title()` is matching the page to an earlier criteria.

Comment: `is_author()` is a conditional tag that determines if the page you're viewing is an author archive, `1` would indicate `true`...(yes you are viewing an author archive).. Have you not got a local dev server you can test on? Why not just open up the theme functions file and look for something hooking onto `wp_title`?

Comment: Yes, yes I know what one the '1' returning means. I tested this because its what `wp_title()` uses internally to return an author. But I missed a filter in my `functions.php`. Thanks! If you want to amend your answer to include "check plugins and your functions file for a filter," I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the offending function and the answer has been amended as requested.. :)